# Can someone explain me what is an API.?

Tags: api, unix, shared-libraries

I've googles about it, yet couldn't understand it properly.. Not sure if it's a library or intra-server communicator..

Can someone explain me in a high-level /low-level what is meant by an API.??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An application-programming interface (API) is a set of programming instructions and standards for accessing a Web-based software application or Web tool. A software company releases its API to the public so that other software developers can design products that are powered by its service.

For example, Amazon.com released its API so that Web site developers could more easily access Amazon's product information. Using the Amazon API, a third party Web site can post direct links to Amazon products with updated prices and an option to "buy now."

An API is a software-to-software interface, not a user interface. With APIs, applications talk to each other without any user knowledge or intervention. When you buy movie tickets online and enter your credit card information, the movie ticket Web site uses an API to send your credit card information to a remote application that verifies whether your information is correct. Once payment is confirmed, the remote application sends a response back to the movie ticket Web site saying it's OK to issue the tickets.

As a user, you only see one interface -- the movie ticket Web site -- but behind the scenes, many applications are working together using APIs. This type of integration is called seamless, since the user never notices when software functions are handed from one application to another.

This article shows an example

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/127316/Integrate-FB-javascript-API-to-your-asp-net-app-to

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Read it from here , will hopefully clear most of your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

An API stands for Application Programming Interface, which means using and existing program or code and accessing it with your code.

===
Example, Search Engine:

Search engine 1: offers search and api (if you want this can be google)
Search engine 2: uses googles api to get results (this is your one)

To get results you basically search the other search engine and get their results to yours

====

An API can be used in many ways, to access others data or code, ect

An in-depth explination can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface